# How to add a unit at the end of textbox in C#

Tags: c#

I find this code from here to add a unit like minutes or kg at the end of a textbox after the number was entered. in C#

```
private void CowAgetxtBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            CowAgetxtBox.Text = CowAgetxtBox.Text + " Month";
        }
    }

    private void CowAgetxtBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            CowAgetxtBox.Text = CowAgetxtBox.Text.Replace(" Month", "");
        }
    }
```

but I don't know how get that number,
I use this Code but it doesn't work

```
int Age = int.Parse(CowAgetxtBox.Text);
```

Comment: what is the value in CowAgetxtBox.Text?

Comment: it's an int variable, for example when user insert number 3 n the textbox it's replace whit 3 month but i wanna use the number in a formule

Comment: You already know how to strip off " Month", just do it again.  Consider a Label.

Comment: Does this function is triggering CowAgetxtBox_Enter

Comment: Is this wpf or windows forms? You probably don't want to modify the text itself but the template of the control if its wpf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do a process similar you when the user focused on the text box.

```
int Age = int.Parse(CowAgetxtBox.Text.Replace(" Month", ""));
```

This will get the job done.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it's not a good idea to put the unit inside the textbox, this will cause a lot of problems in data validation, localization, casting, ...
better to put it outside the textbox :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

```
         CowAgetxtBox.Text
```

this statement contains value other then number thats why this statment

```
        int Age = int.Parse(CowAgetxtBox.Text);
```

is not working  remove " Month" from the first function

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property like the following:

```
int Age {
get { return Convert.ToInt32(CowAgetxtBox.Text.Replace(" Month", ""));     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the unit label changes, this might work in more cases for you:

```
int Age = int.Parse(CowAgetxtBox.Text.Split(' ')[0]);
```